# How can I unbind a UDP port that has no entry in lsof?

Tags: network, macos

On my Mac, I'm having trouble with a UDP port (500) that is "already in use",  but it doesn't have an associated process anymore.

```
sudo netstat -na | grep "udp4.*\.500\>"
```

shows

```
udp4       0      0  192.168.50.181.500     *.*                               
udp4       0      0  192.168.29.166.500     *.*
```

But lsof doesn't show a process on port 500 (ie "sudo lsof -i:500 -P"   reports nothing).

Note that I am using "sudo" for these calls, so it should show all resources.

How can I figure out how to unbind the resource attached to port 500 so I can use it again?

Comment: And if you try `sudo lsof -i@192.168.50.181:500 -P` and `sudo lsof -i@192.168.29.166:500 -P`?

Comment: @Jaume,  blank result, while netstat still shows the ports.  This is driving me nuts, it's making my vpn client not work.